How to create a self-spawning task using tokio rust?
I want to spawn a future/task using tokio that executes some function and before finishing spawns it's own copy.
Uptil now I was using a loop but now I want to do same thing using self-spawning task for desing reasons.
async move {
        loop {
              let mut handle = handle_clone.driver_only.try_lock().unwrap();
              handle.park_timeout(&handle_clone.driver, Duration::from_millis(0));
        }
}


I tried various solution and after encountering many errors the following solution worked for me.

// self-spawning behaviour
fn poll_driver(handle_clone: Arc<Handle>) {
    // Task you want to perform
    let mut handle = handle_clone.driver_only.try_lock().unwrap();
    handle.park_timeout(&handle_clone.driver, Duration::from_millis(0));
    // End of task to perform

    // passing same argument wrapped in Arc<> to enable clone and safe access
    let handle_clone = handle_clone.clone();
    // Can use `tokio::spawn`
    spawn_task(async move {
        poll_driver(handle_clone);
    });
}

// function that spawns async task. In my case i am not using tokio
// you can use tokio::spawn
pub(crate) fn spawn_task<F: Future<Output = ()> + 'static + Send>(future: F) {
    let boxed_future = future.boxed();
    let boxed_task = Arc::new(task::Task {
        future: Mutex::new(boxed_future),
    });
    verona_stubs::verona_schedule_task(boxed_task);
}


and to initiate the task execution.
spawn_task(async {
     poll_driver(handle_clone);
});


I don't think let handle_clone = hanlde_clone.clone() does anything as the original is just going to be dropped at the end of poll_driver
